# Сайт asp.net mvc 5 IIS 10 Обработка ошибок

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http-status-code-404, iis-10

Сайт asp.net mvc 5 IIS 10. Настроил обработку ошибок в web.config, global.asax, и создал контроллер со страничкой для вывода ошибок. Локально протестировал --на IIS под windows10. Все гут,[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Закачал все на продакшен(windows server 2016 IIS), вызвал ошибку и страдаю - результат не достигнут [image: введите сюда описание изображения] В чем может быть проблема? Я немогу запустить отладку на хостинге. Как понять почему там не отображается как задумано и не отрабатывает как на локале? Кстати - на IIS express если запустить, то тоже все отрабатывает отлично [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вам могло бы помочь развитое логгирование событий приложения. А так сложно что-то конкретное предполагать без каких-либо вводных.

Comment: Хостинг настроен на VDS На самом VDS запустил локально - все корректно отрботало

Answer (score 0):

Решить вопрос помогла одна единственная строка  - директива в web.config в разделе system.web `<httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />` Осуществить решение помогли следующие ресурсы - https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2017/Jun/01/Bypassing-IIS-Error-Messages-in-ASPNET  а так же конкретно помог  ответ роберта -(Robert) в списке ответов с рейтингом 2  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13905164/how-to-make-custom-error-pages-work-in-asp-net-mvc-4